# ksqldb REST API push query - reconnect to last consumed offset + 1

Tags: ksqldb

Is it possible to reconnect to the same push query after connection was  lost?

There is a queryId for [terminating](https://docs.ksqldb.io/en/latest/developer-guide/ksqldb-rest-api/streaming-endpoint/#terminating-queries) a query. Is there a similar mechanism which could be used for reconnections via **ksqldb REST API**?

In case that the subscription stopped at offset 5, it should receive also the new messages (without skipping any of them) after offset 5 after reconnection, but without replaying the whole topic from the beginning again.
The ideal would be exactly once processing for all messages (records), but at-least-once semantics are a must have in lot of scenarios.

```
"POST" "http://<ksqldb-host-name>:8088/query-stream"

{
  "sql": "SELECT * FROM Movies EMIT CHANGES;",
  "properties":{"auto.offset.reset":"earliest"}
}
```

Header response with queryID:

```
{"queryId":"f91157c7-cd12-407e-a173-5a4cbc398259","columnNames":["TITLE","ID","RELEASE_YEAR"],"columnTypes":["STRING","INTEGER","INTEGER"]}
```

What I'm probably missing is a programmatic way of committing the offsets.